# Update table column primary key based on mapping table

Tags: sql, oracle, mapping

I have two tables.

1. table contains records with column A (type number, primary key).
2. table contains records with columns A, B (type number). The second represents mapping table.

**What is the problem?**

I need to do remapping all records in table 1, specifically column A to column B based on mapping table 2.
But the problem is that table 1 contains records which have also values B from table 2 (in column A). That means when I will do remapping table 1 then can appear problem with uniqueness because column A in table 1 is primary key.

I have tried to select count of all records which have to be remapped but I dont know exactly if my query is correct.

**Here are those two tables:**

```
select * from temp_1;
select * from temp_2;
```

**Here is the select with count:**

```
SELECT count(*) FROM temp_1 T1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM temp_2 T2 WHERE T2.a = T1.a
and not exists (select 1 from temp_1 T1b where T2.b = T1b.a));
```

**Sample data:**

Table 1:
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, **40, 50**

Table 2:
1-11, 2-22, 3-33, **4-40, 5-50**

Result Table 1 after remapping:
11, 22, 33, **4, 5, 40, 50** remaining problem values

These bold marked values are the problem values if you understand me.

Comment: Can you update your question by telling us which version of SQL (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, etc.) you are using, along with sample data?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The title reads **ORACLE**.

Comment: @FDavidov Sorry...I saw no tags

Comment: @Luke . . . I think I understand the problem, but sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: I have added sample data in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you have table 1 with column A that contains values that may also appear as new values from the re-mapping. The only solution is to use a temporary table into which you deploy the new mapping and, once you are done, copy the new mapping onto table 1.

Comment: Perhaps that is a solution, perhaps it is even the best solution, but it is certainly not the **only** solution. For example, one could drop the PK constraint. Or, if the constraint was defined with DEFERRABLE, it could be deferred (and re-imposed after all the work is done).

Comment: The problem is NOT the uniqueness of the key. The problem is as follows: You have a record with field "A" = 10 and another record with field "A" = 20. When you get the new value for the first record you get 20. Now, when you get the value for the second record it is 40. Now you want to update records whose "A" value is 20 to 40. You will be **wrongly** updating both records.

Comment: And yes, you are right, there may be other solutions, but my guts tell me not to spend efforts looking for them.

Comment: ?? Updates don't work that way. What was 10 will be overwritten with 20, and what was 20 will become 40. There should be no "second pass" over the updated values. Unless I misunderstood what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: @mathguy, you would write `update tablename set A = (select from other table) where A` (or B) `= <something>`. The problem is that a new value for A might collide with an existing value of A in another row. True, if you have uniqueness on A the update will fail, but the aim is not to avoid duplicates but to replace all the values of A with new ones.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it is nice solution but as I thought about it I will have more tables which will need to update. So I would need to create tepmorary mapping table for every table to update. Maybe I could create plsql block which would go through all records in table 1 (in for loop) and update only such records which havent new-values yet. But it can be problem with performance, Im afraid. I dont know what is better. What do you think?

Comment: Indeed. You can make a function/block with variable table names (though the temporary table can be reused if the fields are of the same type). Note that in this case you will need to use **dynamic SQL** and not hardcoded table names. Google for **pl/sql execute immediate examples**. By the way, if this solution satisfies your needs, you may consider to mark it and up-vote it.

Answer (score 0):

**This is not an answer** - posting as one so the query can be formatted.

You may want to check to see if the PK constraint is deferrable. For example, you could run the query below. '......' means your table name, in single quotes (and in ALL CAPS). If the tables aren't yours, query ALL_CONSTRAINTS instead of USER_CONSTRAINTS. If you are lucky, the constraint is deferrable. If not we can think about other solutions. Good luck!

```
select constraint_name, deferrable, deferred
from   user_constraints
where  constraint_type = 'P'
  and  table_name = '.....'
```